# Operand data type void type is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would have a question about the use of null.

If I run this query

```
SELECT SUM(x)
FROM (SELECT NULL AS x) AS DerivedTable
```

I get the error message

> "Operand data type void type is invalid for sum operator."

However, if I create a table with a nullable field and use it within the sum aggregate, it will ignore the NULL value and basically add up all the rest of the records.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(x int)
insert into #temp values (NULL),(3),(5)

SELECT SUM(x) FROM #temp1
```

Result is 8.

Is there a logical explanation of this one?
Would it be because of the data type of NULL has not been declared on the query with the derived table but was declared with the temp table?
Also, I would really like to know if there is a way to produce this error message when run from a table or a derived table, just like the second #temp1 example. Any example which produces this error message when run from a table or a table expression is highly welcome.

Thank you all

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is indeed because the **type of the column cannot be inferred** in your derived table scenario.

If you change the statement and explicitly use a type on the column, the select will work.

```
SELECT SUM(x) FROM (SELECT CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) AS x) AS DerivedTable
```

as will the following statement where the type can be inferred

```
SELECT SUM(x) FROM (SELECT NULL AS x UNION SELECT 1) AS DerivedTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10707)

---

This would also answer your second question. As you can not create a table without declaring the types, there's no way to produce a statement that would generate that specific error message.

Comment: Thank you Lieven,
Do you think of any situation when this error message gets generated through a table or a table expression just like your second example but with a fail.