# No nvarchar: "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator"

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, inferred-type

I have a view that returns `ProductName`, `Qty`, and other columns

Defined as:

```
SELECT ProductName, Qty, /* etc. */ 
FROM SomeConcreteTable
```

`SomeConcreteTable` defines `ProductName` as `nvarchar(40)` and `Qty` as `float`.

```
SELECT ProductName, SUM(Qty) 
FROM MyView
GROUP BY ProductName
```

This causes an error

> Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator

When the view returns no rows, there is no error when the view's `WHERE` conditions are modified so that it returns rows.

```
SELECT ProductName, SUM(COALESCE(vStarts.LotQty, 0))
FROM MyView
GROUP BY ProductName
```

Works regardless of whether the view returns rows.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15332174/161816), Lieven Keersmaekers says that use of an anonymous type in a query had the same issue because the type count not be inferred.

Makes sense.

However, in my case the types should not be inferred -- they are from a table.

Not to ask such an often abused question, but is this a bug?

It seems unexpected behavior that a summation across no rows would yield this error when the summation is against a nullable float (and not a varchar).

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3482.0 (X64)

Answer (score 7):

you should cast your column first and it will work

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Qty as int)) // change to desired type, int for example purposes only
```

Comment: please check if its a float,

Comment: I have made certain it is a float. That is why this is so weird!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your view definition for MyView CASTs or CONVERTs the Qty from a FLOAT to an NVARCHAR. You may have to CAST/CONVERT it back to SUM.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I just created the view and it's a direct SELECT. No view involved has any cast or any other modification in SELECT other than a few name aliases.

Comment: Does explicitly casting the Qty back to float allow the SUM to calculate?

Comment: When I expressly cast to float, the error does indeed go away. I expect this if MSSQL loses track of the data type. It appears as if row data is necessary to get the data type and that `VARCHAR` is assumed otherwise, even when the data type needn't be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue but did not find the cause.
In the "try random things" phase of troubleshooting, I opened the view in SSMS and changed the `FROM` line to use explicit `Database.Schema.Table` notation.
No more error even without the previously required `COALESCE`.
I changed back to the implicit syntax. Still works.
:shrug: Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the view metadata needed refreshing after the definition of the base tables had changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was very simple:
 
Sum(**0**+Qty)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SUM(convert(float,column_name))
```